# discord.js - How would i get all guilds member count and leaving the server if it is below a certain member count

Tags: discord.js

So I'm trying to make my bot so I can make it leave all servers under a certain member count and I would prefer if I could Do It using eval and I'm doing this so when I want to verify my bot It gets denied due to inorganic growth the member count I want it to be set is 50 if anyone could help that would be appreciated

Comment: Sadly not as I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: I just realized I made a syntax error, I have fixed that and I tested on my own bot and it worked on mine. Try the updated answer and let me know

Comment: If it still doesn't work, please update your question with code around how the command is being used

Comment: I'll test it out now thanks.

Comment: Thanks I have tested the code and it worked perfectly thanks so much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code should do the trick

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
    const memberCount = guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size

// This filters out bots and only counts true members

    if (memberCount < 50) {
        guild.leave()
        console.log(`Left the ${guild.name} guild because they only had ${memberCount} members!`)
    }
})
```